# Migrate restkit v0.20

Tags: ios, restkit

Migrated to v0.20 and looks like RKClient deprecated.

Any idea how to set the user name and password? I used to do this in 1.0

```
[[RKClient sharedClient] setUsername:@"username"];
[[RKClient sharedClient] setPassword:@"password"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the RKClient RestKit 0.20 now uses AFNetworking and it's client methods. However you can call the client of the RKObjectManager via `HTTPClient`, so setting the authorization header should be looking like

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"username" 
                                                                      password:@"password"];
```

For all other methods (authorization isn't listed there), check out the [wiki document](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0).